# How can I extract all the cell values (as well as their cell IDs) that have a specific color?

Tags: r, excel, filter

I have a dataset which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI4NJ.jpg).

[image]

I want to create another dataset which only has two columns:

(1) The value/text of all cells that are red
(2) The original cell ID associated with each value/text

Essentially, it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWdi.jpg).

[image]

I am assuming that there is an easy way to do this, but for some reason I haven't been able to make it work on excel (maybe it is because I am using the online version of excel, but I am unsure). I would also be happy to do this using R , in case that is easier.

Thank you in advance!

p.s. Sorry about the weirdly cropped dataset (done for privacy).

Comment: Are you willing to use VBA? Because you can't check the interior color of a cell using only formulas.

Comment: I think the **tidyxl** package might be useful for dealing with Excel files with data/information entered as formatting; will take some processing though.

Comment: @Lucas yes I am willing to do so. Do you have any further advice?

Comment: @joran Would you mind expanding on how I can use tidyxl to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I've never used it myself, I only know that it exists.

Comment: @Mint check my answer, I believe it can guide you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are willing to use VBA and asked for further advise, I wrote the code below to serve as a guide so you can learn, change it and achieve the desired result.

Assuming you have a sheet named '**Colored data**' like this:

[image]

And a sheet named '**Analysis**' like this:

[image]

You can run this code:

```
Sub CompareAndHighlightDifferences()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim cell_color As String
Dim cell_address As String
Dim new_row As Long

Set w1 = Sheets("Colored data")
Set w2 = Sheets("Analysis")

With w1
    For Each cel In .UsedRange
        cell_color = cel.Interior.Color
        cell_address = cel.Address
        new_row = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        w2.Cells(new_row, 1) = cell_address
        With w2.Cells(new_row, 2)
            .Value = cell_color
            .Interior.Color = cell_color
        End With
    Next cel
End With

End Sub
```

And achieve the following results in the sheet '**Analysis**':

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful. I want my 2nd column to include the text value of the original cells... so would I simply do .Value = cell_value ? Not sure what the right syntax for that would be (I tried to google it).

Comment: @Mint since we are iterating each "cel", you should replace ".Value = cell_color" with ".Value = cel.value".
In the code, "cel" is simply a name to call each object inside our loop. I used it instead of "cell" to avoid confusion with the VBA object with the same name.